# Does installing/running Blender tamper in any way with my system/settings or install additional software/required components?

Tags: windows, installation

My question is, does using Blender (since it doesn't require an installation as far as I understand) tamper in any way with my system, install additional/required/third party software or make any long lasting changes to my registry?

I'm using Windows 8.1 64bit with all the current updates at the moment.

Answer (score 6):

No it doesn't modify your system, *provided you are using the self-contained .zip version*.

The **self-contained .zip version** is just that, self-contained. It will - of course - put data where-ever you tell it to. Animation output or other temporary files will be written where you tell Blender to put them. Temporary files (in `C:\tmp\` by default) are deleted every so often.

In addition to the outputs mentioned above, the **Blender Windows *Installer*** will also make a link in you start menu, (possibly) on you desktop and will associate `.blend` files with the Blender executable. This file association is done via the registry but should be harmless.

Comment: Just to be clear, only temporary files (files in `C:\Temp`) will be deleted. Saved renders/animation output will not be spontaneously removed ;)

Comment: @gandalf3 Right, no more answering questions at 1am local-time for me (and then editing at 3am) ;D